# Are the cases in Latin always six?

Tags: declension, history, case, definitions

In a book about linguistics I've read this sentence:

> Each word has up to six different such 'cases', and each case has distinct endings for singular and plural.

Now I'm pretty sure that when I studied latin for 1 year during middle school and 5 years during high school, the latin cases were always (I mean, in every declension, and more in general in every discussion) referred to as 6 in number, whether some of them have the same ending or not.

But the sentence above gives me 1% chance that I might be wrong and that you count *n* cases with the same ending as 1. Which also means that given a noun I might find plural and singular have different number of cases. Which pulls that 1% down to 1‰.

But why not asking?

Furthermore, I've not studied the history of the latin language, so I have no idea whether there where more cases in earlier times, which would make me think that there could have been a time where some words had, say, 6 cases, while others had 7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, most nouns and adjectives have six cases (nominative, genitive, dative, accusative, ablative, and vocative). However, this isn't always the case.

Some words are defective, where they appear to lack a case, and not just because of lack of attestation. These include very popular nouns like *fas*, *nefas*, *nihil*, and *opus*. You can see a fuller list of them in [Allen and Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/nouns-defective-cases).

With other words, however, there's a seventh case: the locative. Words which have a locative case are usually where you can be, so you can find *humi*, *domi*, and *ruri* for *humus*, *domus*, and *rus*. You'll also see it with cities, so *Romae* or *Carthagini* are locative forms.

Comment: You should probably mention the vocative, which aside from a certain class of words is *always* identical to the nominative in form. (Without that exception, wouldn't we just say the nominative subsumed the vocative, just as the ablative subsumed the instrumental case?)

Comment: @chepner It is however notable, mi astutissime Hepnere, that that little exception happens to encompass a great deal of male names, plus masculine adjectives, so the distinctive vocative is actually all over the place ;-)

Comment: True. I guess I'm just not weighting by vocabulary size :)

Answer (score 6):

Furthermore, outside of non-neuter words in the second declension the nominative and vocative aren't formally distinct, and for neuter nouns of any declension, the nominative and accusative aren't formally distinct either.

Additionally, in o-stems (i.e. the second declension) and many i-stems (a subset of the third declension) the dative and ablative aren't formally distinct, with the singular for both ending in *-ō* (for the o-stems) or *-ī* (i-stems; analogy with other words in the third declension introduced *-e* for the ablative for many i-stems as well, though), and the plural in *-īs* (o-stems) or *-ibus* (i-stems)—the dative and ablative plural are never distinct in any paradigm, but the singular usually is.

Obviously the vocative resp. dative/ablative are all still *felt* to be distinct cases by speakers even if they're formally indistinguishable, as e.g. agreeing adjectives in different paradigms demonstrate, but this could be what your source was referring to.